# How do I access the properties of these C# objects?

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a list of objects in C# as follows:

```
var items = new List<object> {
    new { id = 1, parentId = 0, children = new List<object>() },
    new { id = 2, parentId = 3, children = new List<object>() },
    new { id = 3, parentId = 1, children = new List<object>() },
    new { id = 4, parentId = 0, children = new List<object>() }
};
```

I want to access, for example, the `id` property of the first object in the list, but when I do something like the following:

```
items[0].id
```

I get the following error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no accessible
>   extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'object'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

How can I access the properties of the four object literals in the C# list of objects above?
Thanks.

Comment: i'd consider writing a class for those. `dynamic` is one way, but has overhead at runtime.

Comment: Looks like you want a list of dictionaries, not plain objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a more c# way of doing things here.

```
class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<A> Children { get; } = new List<A>();
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<A> {
            new A { Id = 1, ParentId = 0},
            new A { Id = 2, ParentId = 3},
            new A { Id = 3, ParentId = 1},
            new A { Id = 4, ParentId = 0}
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this way with classes definitely makes the most sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic since you particularly dont know about the type

```
var items = new List<object> {
                   new { id = 1, parentId = 0, children = new List<object>() },
                   new { id = 2, parentId = 3, children = new List<object>() },
                   new { id = 3, parentId = 1, children = new List<object>() },
                   new { id = 4, parentId = 0, children = new List<object>() }
};
dynamic dy = items[0];
Console.WriteLine(dy.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a type with the properties you need:

```
     public class Foo {

        public Foo(){ 
          Children = new List<Foo>();
        }

            public int Id {get;set;}
            public int? ParentId {get;set;}
            public List<Foo> Children  {get;set;}

        }

   }
```

then:

```
var items = new List<Foo> {
    new { id = 1, ParentId = 0 },
    new { id = 2, ParentId = 3},
    new { id = 3, ParentId = 1},
    new { id = 4, ParentId = 0}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To access members of an `object` you need to cast it to its type where that member is defined. It would be a bit tricky, because type is anonymous, but not impossible:

```
var items = new List<object> {
    new { id = 1, parentId = 0, children = new List<object>() },
    new { id = 2, parentId = 3, children = new List<object>() },
    new { id = 3, parentId = 1, children = new List<object>() },
    new { id = 4, parentId = 0, children = new List<object>() }
};
T Cast<T>(T ignore, object obj) => (T)obj;
var typedNull = true ? null : new { id = default(int), parentId = default(int), children = default(List<object>) };
var typedObject = Cast(typedNull, items[2]);
Console.WriteLine(typedObject.id);
Console.WriteLine(typedObject.parentId);
```

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

But you better to declare your own named type for this purpose instead.